# Load config file without restart shell / Chef

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, chef-infra

I using `Chef` for setting up machine, I need to install `rbenv` too, but I can't use `rbenv` command in my script after installing it, because it start work only after I restart terminal or  run `source .bashrc` command outside of the script. Same things are when I try to path env variables to `.bash_profile`. How solve this problem?

```
 bash 'install_rbenv' do
   interpreter "bash"
   cwd '/home/vagrant'
   user 'vagrant'
   code <<-EOH
     git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
     echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
     echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
     EOH
 end
```

Comment: you can source your file at the end of your provisioning script

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I tried to do it right after I realized what the problem was

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables can't be passed from a child process back to the parent so you'll have to source it in every `bash` resource you want to use with rbenr or do `ENV['PATH'] = "whatever:#{ENV['PATH']}"` in your recipe code. In general I don't recommend using rbenv with servers at all, there are usually better options.